# Help center article inaccuracy

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, help-center

I'm wondering about these words [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

```
but if your question generally covers…
 ...
 - software tools commonly used by programmers;

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
```

And after that:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
> library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
> Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
> it.

It sounds a bit contradictory. Maybe you could rephrase it somehow.

Please explain if I'm wrong about that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, one can still ask how to use specific tools or about functions of them.

Comment: `commonly used` means that I want to hear some recommendations or get some opinions which may lead to spam answers, no?

Comment: @OlegMeleshko no, that's not what that means

Answer (score 3):

The key word here is *recommend* .

Questions about the usage of a tool are OK, and we have a lot of them. Questions asking us to recommend a tool are off-topic.

We might want to emphasise the word "recommend" in the FAQ, but personally I don't believe it is necessary.

Slightly off-topic, we do have the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site if you need a recommendation. Just make sure that a recommendation question fits the requirements there.

Comment: I was confused by `commonly used` there. `Recommend` word is super clear for me.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko Just as a note, the "find" part is also important. I've seen people insist that their request is on topic because they aren't asking to be told which tool is the best (& therefore isn't opinion based). Just asking the community to find something for them is off topic.